# Python TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is meaning of the error and where is the mistake?
I got the `TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable` for the following line:

```py
row = random.choice(get_the_valid_locations[-2])
```

here is the get_the_valid_locations function:

```py
def get_the_valid_locations(board):
        valid_locations = []
        for col in range(COLS_OF_BOARD):
            for row in range(ROWS_OF_BOARD):
                if available_square(board, row, col):
                    valid_locations.extend([row, col])
        return valid_locations
```

`get_the_valid_locations[-2]` is an `int` (I checked).

If you need more Code just ask for it the comments!

Comment: you're using subscription operator instead of using function calling

Comment: how should I do it instead?

Comment: it's unclear what `-2` is supposed to be. Presumably you want element at index -2 from the list returned by `get_the_valid_locations`. However you need to call that function and pass argument for `board` (2D list?). We don't know what object/variable you want to pass for board.

Comment: please, post [mre]

Comment: @buran you're right that's why I deleted my answer as it is not useful and may mislead. I wonder from where ```COLS_OF_BOARD``` and ```ROWS_OF_BOARD``` is coming from. Probably global variables?

Comment: for board I want to pass on (board). And the -2 is because I only want the last two of the list.

Comment: @Sajid, yes, they should be global names, presumably constants (being ALL_CAPS), but it's not realy needed to loop using range, there are better ways. Of course, all this is just guess - there is lack of details,

Comment: COLS_OF_BOARD and  ROWS_OF_BOARD = 4. It is a 4 by 4 board.

Comment: if I understand correctly `row = random.choice(get_the_valid_locations(board)[-2:])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line that gives the error has a small mistake. 
 Now you try to take the second to last element of a *function*, but you I think you to give `-2` as an argument to the function. 
 In that case the line should be:

```
row = random.choice(get_the_valid_locations(-2))
```

Then `row` will contain a random element from the output of your function.
**EDIT**

 A comment (credits: [buran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4046632/buran)) noted that the function requires a 2d array, in that case I think you mean well, but implement it wrong. You want the output to be an array of colums and an array of rows. Your statement would be used to choose a random value of the rows returned by the functions.

 You could do it like this:

```
def get_the_valid_locations(board):
    valid_rows = []
    valid_columns = []
    for col in range(COLS_OF_BOARD):
        for row in range(ROWS_OF_BOARD):
            if available_square(board, row, col):
                valid_rows.append(row)
                valid_columns.append(col)
    return [valid_rows, valid_columns]
```

usage:

```
randomRow = random.choice(get_the_valid_locations(board)[0])
```

or

```
randomColumn = random.choice(get_the_valid_locations(board)[1])
```

Note: if you just want a random position on the `board` object, your code is correct, but your call should be:

```
row = random.choice(get_the_valid_locations(board))
```

Comment: `get_the_valid_locations` expects argument for `board`, most likely 2d list. calling it with board=-2 will cause error.

Comment: Yes I think buran is right. Is there a possibility I can put both (board) and (-2) inside?

Comment: I made some edits, if they don't cover your problem, try explaining it a bit more

Answer (score 0):

assuming `board` is a name that you want to pass as argument for parameter `board` and you want just last 2 elements of the list returned from the function:

```
row = random.choice(get_the_valid_locations(board)[-2:])
```

This will randomly select one value out 0f the 2 last values.